# Same pattern in grep and sed select different values

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, non-greedy

I want to create a pattern for sed, which will find out 'type=""
For this I tried to use the pattern

> type=".*\?"

```
echo 'aa type="none" stretchChildren="first"' | sed s/'type=".*\?"'/hello/
```

Above is the sed command which prints

> aa hello

Which means it selects 'type="none" stretchChildren="first"' for 'type=".*\?"'

Now below is the grep command using same pattern on same string

```
 echo 'aa type="none" stretchChildren="first"' | grep -oP 'type=".*?"'
```

It gives output

> type="none"

Don't know what I am missing in sed pattern

Can some one help me out here
Output of sed should be

> aa hello stretchChildren="first"

Comment: Which platform are you on?  You're making non-portable assumptions about dialects of `grep` and `sed`.  It looks as though you're probably on Linux or using GNU `sed` and `grep`, but it would be as well to say so.

Comment: Why not use a simply pattern: `type="[^"]*"` which will work the same in `sed` and `grep` without extra options and does what you seem to want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` doesn't have non-greedy pattern matching, so using `*?` or `*\?` won't work.

If you want to have the same output as grep then use a grouping without the `"` - `[^"]+` instead of `".*?"`:

```
sed -r 's/type="[^"]+"/hello/'
```

`[`, `]` is a group of characters, `^` is a negation, so `[^"]` means any character that is not a `"`.

For OSX use `-E` instead of `-r`.
(`-E` also works on latest GNU sed, but it is not documented in `--help` nor in `man sed` so I don't recommend it)

Comment: [^"]+ - What does it mean in this pattern

Comment: at least one (`+`) occurance of all characters except `"`"

Comment: ++; if you use `-E` instead of `-r`, it'll also work on OSX (in this particular case).